# How to sync MySQL's time with system time without mysql restart?

Tags: mysql, configuration, timestamp, timezone

On my machine I have a service to synchronise the SYSTEM time (including Time zone), and would like the DB will synchronize with the machine time once in a while.

When I change SYSTEM time, MySQL keep giving the old time when I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, It synchronize it only when I restart the MySQL service.

I would like to ask: is it possible, by update some system variable, or anything else, to set the DB time, to be equal to the SYSTEM time, or any other time, without a restart of the service?

I don't want to stop the DB at all. I think that maybe a sceduled task, which run once in a while, can be set, but what should it do?

To accept answer, it must pass the following test:

```
# change system time, date or timezone on the machine
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual; #--still show old time
call sync_time; #or some sync date + time + timezone commands... 
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual; #--will show updated time
```

I just need the sync_time procedure, that will cause the last select to show the machine date and local time.

@rathishDBA answer didn't helped at all, it only changed the MySQL variables, not sync the DB time. I tried it as the 'root' user and both first and last select gave me the same unsynced result.

For example see this picture:
[image: screen shot]

```
System time = 2:07
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = 11:37
```

Comment: Windows server 2008 64 bit or above

Comment: What timezone is Windows set to?

Comment: I changed it several times for tests, I guess in the sample it was set to my time zone +2.5 hrs. the point is that there is difference. should I recompile the DB to solve the problem? it is the same in MySQL and in MariaDB

Comment: What datatype are you using?  `DATETIME`?  Or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Comment: @RickJames Both `now()` and `current_timestamp()` show unsynced time. I'm starting from **GMT Standard Time** and change it to some other value, for example **W. Europe Standard Time**. it shows the correct time after DB restart.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me, I hope it will work for you too:

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-10-26 15:13:16 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> show global variables like '%time_zone%';
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| system_time_zone | India Standard Time |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM              |
+------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.18 sec)

mysql>
```

You need `SUPER` privilege to set this configuration value on run time to avoid system restart.

Comment: sorry, it didn't worked for me, I see the **old timestamp**,it will affect only after MySQL restart. see the edit in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question; you are correct that you can only set the timezone on startup, but if you set `SYSTEM` then that means any subsequent calls to get the time will simply [be passed to the OS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html). So if you see the time not change in MySQL then whatever you are doing in the OS to change it isn't being applied at that level.

A quick [browse of the source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/mysys/my_getsystime.c) shows calls to `gettimeofday()` to get the system time.

Comment: see the screen shot I've uploaded: timestamp is different from system time, any replace doesn't reflected by the db untill DB restart. maybe this problem  is only on windows